# How with formspree use preventDefault()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, forms, ref

I'm struggling with issue that my react form doesn't reset after clicking submit. I'm using antd form with sending mails with formspree.
How I can manage my code for resetting values of my input fields with non reloading page after submitting form?

```
const [token, setToken] = useState<string>('');
  const [state, handleSubmit] = useForm('xxxxxxxx');

  if (state.succeeded) {
    formRef.current.message.success('Message sent');
  }

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <MessageForm
        ref={formRef}
        name='nest-messages'
        onFinish={handleSubmit}
        validateMessages={validateMessages}
      >
        {FormItems.map((item) => (
          <Form.Item
            key={item.name}
            name={['user', item.name]}
          >
            {item.inputType}
          </Form.Item>
        ))}

        <Form.Item>
          <HCaptcha
            sitekey='xxxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx'
            onVerify={setToken}
            ref={captchaRef}
          />
          <SendButton type='primary' htmlType='submit' disabled={!token}>
            Wyślij wiadomość
          </SendButton>
        </Form.Item>
      </MessageForm>
```

Answer (score 1):

antd has a `resetFields` option. You could do something like that in your handleSubmit function:

```
formRef.current.resetFields();
```